# Placing cameras on the scene

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, camera, origin

I am trying to place my cameras generated, on the scene. Instead it is being placed on the origin. I am stuck here and need guidance as to how to place on the scene in 4 different locations on the scene.

```
for i in range(4):

    name = "Camera"

    # create camera data
    cam_data = bpy.data.cameras.new("{}.{:03d}".format(name, i))

    # create object camera data and insert the camera data
    cam_ob = bpy.data.objects.new("{}{:03d}".format(name, i), cam_data)

    # link into scene
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(cam_ob)

bpy.context.scene.update()
```

Comment: Set `cam_ob.location`.

Comment: Thank you! :) @batFINGER. Is it possible to integrate that in the for loop?